# Change the format of a numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a (2x2) `numpy` array which contains an (1x3) list, like this below:

```
[[ 1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6]
 [ 7, 8, 9], [10,11,12]]
```

and I want to break it to single elements like this (2x6) array *(or matrix, I can't tell the difference)*:

```
[ 1, 2, 3,  4,  5,  6]
[ 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I can create the second array by coping every single element of the first array and put it to the second one. Yet I wonder if there is a more easy way provided by the `numpy` library.

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic can you show the minimum code necessary to produce an array that matches what you expect your input to look like?

Comment: Your first display is ambiguous.  Is it really a (2,2) object dtype arrays with lists, or is it a (2,2,3) array of numbers?  If the latter a simple reshape will work `np.reshape(arr, (2,6))`.  But if the former, `np.array(arr.tolist())` might be a useful first step.

Comment: For your existing array `my_array`, could you please share the exact value output for `my_array.dtype` and `my_array.shape`?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use resize function to do this

```
import numpy as np
a=[[ 1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6],
 [ 7, 8, 9], [10,11,12]]
a = numpy.array(a)
a.resize(2,6)
print(a)
```

OUTPUT

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: If you aren't changing the total number of elements, `reshape` is preferable to `resize` (whether function or method).